Inherit statement_timeout value from role to individual users in POSTGRES
I want to set statement_timeout value for 2 roles :

admin_user where we have 3 users and
select_user where we have 10 users

When I set statement_timeout for individual users, it is working fine, but when I set statement_timeout for admin_user role and select_user role and assign users to these roles, they are not inheriting the statement_timeout.
All these users also have other roles which do not have any statement_timeout set.
When I check using show statement_timeout query, value is 0 which is default value for individual user when individual user logs in.
Can someone please let me know if statement_timeout values can be inherited by the individual users within the role or we should set the value at individual user level in this scenario?
